# Pandas multiples conditions resulting in zeros

Tags: python, pandas

The pandas conditional statement resulting in '0' while evaluating below conditions in pandas, not sure why the results are not printing as required.

```
Source:
t_type  Att       Name
ABC     NaN       A1     
CCC     A_XY      NaN     
ABC     NaN       NaN         
CDE     NaN       NaN            
CDE     A_ZZ      A2
ABC     A_DD      A4
```

Code used for this is:

```
conditions = [
(df['t_type'] == 'ABC') & (df['Att'].isnull()) & (df['Name'].notnull()), 
(df['t_type'] != 'ABC') & (df['Att'].notnull()) & (df['Name'].isnull()),
(df['t_type'] == 'ABC') & (df['Att'].isnull()) & (df['Name'].isnull()),
(df['t_type'] != 'ABC') & (df['Att'].isnull()) & (df['Name'].isnull())
]
values = ['Att is Null','Name is Null','ABC - Att and Name is Null','Non ABC - Att and Name is Null']

df['Remarks'] = np.select(conditions, values)

print(df.to_string())
```

Expected output:

```
t_type  Att       Name   Remarks
ABC     NaN       A1     Att is Null
CCC     A_XY      NaN    Name is Null
ABC     NaN       NaN    ABC Att and Name is Null
CDE     NaN       NaN    Non ABC Att and Name is Null
CDE     A_ZZ      A2
ABC     A_DD      A4
```

Comment: I think you need an additional condition that looks like this `(df['t_type'].notnull) & (df['Att'].notnull()) & (df['Name'].notnull())` and an addtional value that is just an empty string to get the expected results.

Answer (score 2):

`Numpy.select` has a `default` parameter, you can specify it to be whatever you want:

```
df['Remarks'] = np.select(conditions, values, np.NaN)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  t_type   Att Name                         Remarks
0    ABC   NaN   A1                     Att is Null
1    CCC  A_XY  NaN                    Name is Null
2    ABC   NaN  NaN      ABC - Att and Name is Null
3    CDE   NaN  NaN  Non ABC - Att and Name is Null
4    CDE  A_ZZ   A2                             nan
5    ABC  A_DD   A4                             nan
```

Comment: Just adding a information from official documents [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), that `np.select` has one parameter, which can be set for the cases where no conditions matched. 
`numpy.select(condlist, choicelist, default=0)`

Comment: so you could just make it `np.select(conditions, values, "")` to make it not even show up.

Comment: It is not about the default value. The conditions are not being evaulated w.r.t the above source data w.r.t to the Remarks results

Comment: Actually sharing the output you're getting sounds like it'd be helpful... My output comes directly from copy/pasting your code, and it works fine.